# Any ways to define grouped conditional dependencies in debian/control?

Tags: python, debian, packaging, python-2.x, dpkg

I'm debianizing a Python package, which has a bit weird dependencies. It either:

- Depends on `python2.7`
- Depends on `python2.6` and `python-ordereddict` (my self-built package for `ordereddict` on PyPI)

For example, in my `setup.py` I have:

```
deps = ["Flask >=0.8"]
if not hasattr(collections, "OrderedDict"): # Python 2.6
    deps.append("ordereddict")

setup(
    …
    install_requires=deps,
    …
)
```

I haven't found anything in Debian packaging documentation on this matter. Just out of the blue I've tried writing

```
Depends: ..., python2.7 | (python2.6, python-ordereddict)
```

But, no surprisingly, it is a wrong syntax that didn't work:

```
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: can't parse dependency (python2.6
```

I'm using dh_python2 and `${python:Depends}` provides quite unreasonable list like

```
Depends: python2.7 | python2.6, python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2),
    python (<< 2.8), python-flask, python-ordereddict
```

With such dependency list, it'll require `python-ordereddict` for `python2.7`, that does not exist. And obviously I can't patch `python2.7-minimal` to say `Provides: python-ordereddict` (like it's done with `python-argparse`).

Any suggestions on how to correctly package such library, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to let `python-ordereddict` depend on `python2.6`, then let your main package depend on `python2.7 | python-ordereddict`. I'm assuming it doesn't make sense to install `python-ordereddict` with 2.7, since `OrderedDict` is available in that release.

Of course, that's ugly because it pushes the dependency of the main package into the library. The alternative is to realize that dependencies must be propositional formulas in [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (CNF). By applying the [distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributivity#Propositional_logic) of propositional logic, you can convert

```
python2.7 | (python2.6, python-ordereddict)
```

to the equivalent CNF

```
python2.7 | python2.6, python2.7 | python-ordereddict
```

(which, I admit, isn't particularly pretty either).